# Dynamic DNS service will slow down your traffic?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, internet

I don't have a static IP but it seems my internet provider never changed my ip address. I am setting up a vpn server and it will be used by myself only.

I know the benefit of using dynamic DNS service. My question is is it true that  all my traffic, in or out, will be routed to the dynamic DNS service provider site if I use the dynamic DNS service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is incorrect.  Dynamic DNS *only* maps your IP to a name.  DNS is quick and only done once to match the name to the address.  No traffic flows to a DNS provider, other than the one-time domain name lookup.

However, everything *will* flow through your VPN provider.  If you are using a hosted VPN provider, then all your traffic will flow through that provider, then to you.  If you are hosting the VPN yourself, then there would be no extra hops.

Also note, just because your IP address hasnt changed, that doesnt mean it wont.  You may be on a long DHCP lease, or have a NATed address.  However, the fact you are using a DDNS provider should alleviate any issues.